# Pandas - Expand table based on different email with same key from another table

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I have a quick one that I am struggling with.

Table 1 has a lot of user information in addition to an email column and a unique ID column.
Table 2 has only a unique ID column and an email column. These emails can be different from table 1, but do not have to be.

I am attempting to merge them such that table 1 expands only to include new rows when there is a new email from table 2 on the same unique id.

Example:

```
Table 1: 

id   email   first_name    last_name 
1    jo@       joe          king
2    john@     johnny       maverick
3    Tom@      Tom          J


Table 2: 

id   email   
2    johnmk@  
3    TomT@  
8    Jared@


Desired Output:

id   email   first_name    last_name 
1    jo@       joe          king
2    john@     johnny       maverick
2    johnmk@   johnny       maverick
3    Tom@      Tom          J
3    TomT@     Tom          J
```

I would have expected `pd.merge(table1, table2, on = 'id', how = 'left')` to do this, but this just generates  the email columns with the suffix _x, _y.

How can I make the merge?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can try `pd.concat` with a boolean mask using `isn` for `df2` , with `groupby.ffill`:

```
out = pd.concat((df1,df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]),sort=False)
out.update(out.groupby("id").ffill())
out = out.sort_values("id")#.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   id    email first_name last_name
0   1      jo@        joe      king
1   2    john@     johnny  maverick
0   2  johnmk@     johnny  maverick
2   3     Tom@        Tom         J
1   3    TomT@        Tom         J
```

Comment: That definitely solves the problem, its just so dirty!

Comment: @WolVes May be , you can wait to see if you find something cleaner :)

Comment: you definitely get an upvote and I really appreciate your help. I don't have a better answer =D . I will keep it open a bit though just to see if someone comes up with something interesting.